# Como criar um gerador de numeros apartir de um numero Inicial e um numero Final?

Tags: php, javascript

Não sei se faz em php ou javascript, já li tutoriais mas não consegui chegar em lugar nenhum... eu gostaria de criar um sistema pra que eu colocasse um numero inicial e um final e nesse intervalo teria 20.000 numeros e que fossem gerados aleatorios!

exemplo:

> 85000 numero inicial

85659

85325

...

> 95000 numero final

```html
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inicial">Inicial</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inicial" placeholder="Número Inicial">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="final">Final</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="final" placeholder="Número Final">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Iniciar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Poste o que vc tentou fazer, que ajuda. Sobre ser PHP ou JS, só depende da finalidade. Se for algo que não pode ser alterado pelo usuário, melhor do lado do PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma abaixo usando essa função `randomNumber` em JavaScript:

```
function randomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(((max + 1) - min) * Math.random() + min);
}

alert(randomNumber(85659, 85325));
```

Solução baseada no seu HTML em JavaScript:

```js
function randomNumber(min, max) {
 return Math.floor( ((max + 1) - min) * Math.random() + min);
}

function gerarNumeros() {

  var txtInicial = document.getElementById('inicial'),
   txtFinal = document.getElementById('final'),
    result = document.getElementById('result');
    
  var numeroInicial = parseInt(txtInicial.value),
   numeroFinal = parseInt(txtFinal.value);
  
  var count = 0;
  
  var intervalo = setInterval(function() {

    //Gerando 20 números por vez. 
    for (var i = 0; i < 20/*20000*/; i++) {
      
      var numeroGerado = randomNumber(numeroInicial, numeroFinal);
    result.innerHTML = result.innerHTML + '<p>' + count + ' : ' + numeroGerado + '</p>';
      
      count++;
      
  }
    
    if (count === 20000) {//Quando o total de números gerados for 20000, parar de gerar.
     clearInterval(intervalo);
    }

  }, 1000);//Gerar em 1 e 1 segundo.

}
```

```css
p {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inicial">Inicial</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inicial" placeholder="Número Inicial">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="final">Final</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="final" placeholder="Número Final">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="gerarNumeros()">Iniciar</button>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Solução baseada no seu HTML em PHP:

```
<?php

$numeroInicial = 85325;//$_GET['inicial'];
$numeroFinal = 85659;//$_GET['final'];

echo '<h1>Resultado:</h1>';

for ($i = 0; $i < 20000; $i++) {
    echo '<p>' . $i . ' : ' . mt_rand($numeroInicial, $numeroFinal) . '</p>';   
}
```

Comment: No caso aqui, como eu faria pra imprimir todos os 20.000 em uma outra pagina ? ou poderia ser em baixo mesmo !

Comment: Alterei o exemplo, mas com 20 números gerados.

Comment: mas como eu faria pra gerar os 20.000 ?

Comment: Só alterar o for para 20000, onde está comentado.

Comment: 20.000 trava kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk, você poderia me ajudar so mais essa vez, como faria pra gerar de um por um ou de 20 em 20, na mesma pagina, tipo descendo....

Comment: Se você fazer da segunda forma com PHP deve demorar, mas gerar.

Comment: 20k de clicks também é demais, não tem como adicionarmos um timer pra ir gerando apartir desse codigo ?

Comment: agora foi, obrigado !

Answer (score 7):

### Solução em JS

```js
return Math.random() * (max - min) + min; // float, e não inclui o max
```

ou

```js
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; // inteiros sem o max
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; // inteiros incluso max
```

Para entender a diferença das versões, veja esta postagem:

[Por que preciso multiplicar o Math.random() um número acima do valor para usar com Math.floor()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/560287/70)

### Solução em PHP

```php
rand( int $min , int $max )
```

Veja demonstração em JS:

```html
<button onclick="document.body.innerHTML += (Math.floor(Math.random() * ( 95000 - 85000 ) + 85000 ) + '<br>' );">Gerar</button><br>
```