# Por que preciso multiplicar o Math.random() um número acima do valor para usar com Math.floor()?

Tags: javascript, matemática, random, switch

Fiz um código JavaScript que gera um numero aleatório e entra em um case do switch aleatoriamente.

Na minha cabeça, se colocasse multiplicado por 2 já entraria no `case` número 2, no entanto precisei fazer vezes 3.

Segue o código pra melhor entendimento:

```
    var numero = Math.floor(3* Math.random());
    
    switch(numero){
        case 0:
            alert('foi 0');
            break;
        case 1:
            alert('foi 1');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('foi 2');
            break;
        default:
            alert('n foi nenhum');
            break;
    }
```

Se eu por acaso colocasse um quarto `case`, deveria multiplicar por 4? `case 5` por 5, etc.?

Comment: As respostas já explicaram que `Math.floor(n * Math.random())` vai gerar um número inteiro entre  zero e `n` (sendo que o `n` não é incluso). No seu caso, portanto, o resultado será 0, 1 ou 2, e portanto nunca vai cair no `default`. Na verdade, pra esse código específico nem precisa do `switch`, poderia ser apenas `alert('Foi ' + numero)`

Answer (score 6):

Isso me dá a oportunidade de responder o que é mais importante do que o problema em si.

O que temos aí é a observação do sintoma, mas ele não é o problema.

Quando for programar, e na verdade quando for resolver qualquer problema, você precisa olhar para o real problema e não onde apenas pode observar o problema. Por isso que existe um conceito chamado [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para colocar dúvidas em qualquer lugar, aqui no SOpt nós apenas reforçamos mais isso. Ou seja, você precisa olhar o que importa do problema, nada mais que isso, e claro deve colocar tudo o que é necessário no problema.

A gente reconhece que quem está começando tem dificuldade de entender onde está o problema, e eu vou dizer sobre ele adiante, mas quero destacar a importância de entender qual é o real problema mais que tudo, só assim a pessoa se desenvolve na programação. Porque entender os mecanismos de linguagens é fácil, o difícil é resolver problemas. Então tenha isso em mente o tempo todo.

Vamos ignorar completamente o `switch` porque ele não é a questão, ele nem é necessário até mesmo neste código, ele só responde ao que recebeu e que foi definido antes. Este mecanismo não age de forma especial porque algo foi multiplicado antes ou usou algo randômico, ou por qualquer outra questão, tudo isso é [ortogonal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101), portanto o `switch` funciona com qualquer dado que venha. Para ele só existe algo que seja 0, 1, 2 ou outra coisa diferente desses três valores, neste caso específico.

Veja como o dado se comporta, é só isso que importa (execute várias vezes já que dará resultados diferentes em cada uma delas):

```js
var num = Math.random();
console.log(Math.floor(num));
console.log(num);
console.log(1 * num);
console.log(2 * num);
console.log(3 * num);
console.log(4 * num);
console.log(5 * num);
console.log(Math.floor(1 * num));
console.log(Math.floor(2 * num));
console.log(Math.floor(3 * num));
console.log(Math.floor(4 * num));
console.log(Math.floor(5 * num));
```

O que importa é a geração do número. **A função randômica gera um valor entre 0 até o valor decimal permitido anterior ao 1**. Se ele te servir pode usá-lo de forma direta. E isso você precisa saber aprendendo algo da programação, e de forma específica da linguagem, e para alcançar o objetivo deve ler a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

A outra questão do problema é matemática pura, nada tem a ver com programação. Se você quer proporcionalizar um valor original que vai até 1 precisa calculá-lo multiplicando pelo valor máximo que ele pode atingir. Então se deseja que o valor seja igual ou maior que 1 certamente precisa dessa multiplicação. Se deseja que vá quase a 3 deve multiplicar por 3, se quer que vá quase até 10 deve multiplicar por 10.

O início sempre será partindo do 0, a não ser que faça uma soma para deslocar esse valor inicial, e que provavelmente deve tirar esse valor do máximo. Não vou entrar em detalhes, mas tem dezenas ou centenas de perguntas aqui no site sobre isso, é só pesquisar. Novamente, matemática pura.

Note que eu usei o `random()`, mas nem ele é necessário para indicar sobre a questão central da pergunta, ele é o fato gerador do número. Eu posso fazer o mesmo sem ele, e agora de forma determinística e permite verificar melhor o que se deseja (o exemplo mínimo que se atenta ao que importa):

```js
var num = 0.8346254; //tem que ser entre 0 e o maior valor antes de 1
console.log(Math.floor(num));
console.log(num);
console.log(1 * num);
console.log(2 * num);
console.log(3 * num);
console.log(4 * num);
console.log(5 * num);
console.log(Math.floor(1 * num));
console.log(Math.floor(2 * num));
console.log(Math.floor(3 * num));
console.log(Math.floor(4 * num));
console.log(Math.floor(5 * num));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Math/Random.js).

Aprenda decompor o problema e apresentar cada parte da solução dada para ver o que está acontecendo. Programar não é dar o resultado, é saber como o resultado acontece, é sobre o processo que resulta em algo e não o final dele. Não importa ver a mágica, tem que ver como ela é feita. Passo por passo.

Então a "matemágica" é você chegar até ao valor que deseja em cima desse valor decimal obtido no gerador randômico, e depois cortar a parte decimal que não é necessária para uso posterior, no caso no `switch`.

Para deixar bem claro, o `switch` e a quantidade de `case`s será determinada pela multiplicação e não o contrário.

Sobre o [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

Answer (score 5):

O método `Math.random()` gera um número de 0 até 1 (sendo que não inclui o 1), e quando vc multiplica por três, o que acontece é que gera um número sempre menor que 3. Então mesmo se o `Math.random()` der 0.9999999, o máximo que ele alcança pode ser 2.9999999 que com o `Math.floor()` desce pra 2.

Comment: Destacando bem o "sendo que não inclui o 1", que é o núcleo da resposta. Se o desenvolvedor tivesse resolvido que o "random" incluisse o número do extremo final (ainda bem que não o fez nesse caso), teria  um problema de muito raramente dar 3 exato, e em proporção diferente do resto.

Comment: Entendi. Então se por acaso eu quiser fazer 12 cases (começando por 0, seria até o 11). Eu teria que multiplicar por 12.

Creio que uma forma rápida de pensar, é colocar multiplicado pelo tanto de cases que vão ter, certo? 15 Cases, seria multiplicado por 15.

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) tem a citação relevante em causa: "retorna um número pseudo-aleatório no intervalo [0, 1[, ou seja, de 0 (inclusivo) até, mas não incluindo, 1 (exclusivo)".
Se olhar para o exemplo na mesma página sobre `getRandomIntInclusive` vê que eles acrescentam 1 ao numero precisamente para compensar o exclusivo.